# Entregar parte decimal de un numero

Tags: python, visual-studio

Como puedo hacer para que el programa solo me de la parte decimal?
realice un codigo simple que funciona con numero positivos, pero al cambiar a uno negativo no me da el resultado que quiero.

```
dato = float(input("dime un numero: "))

decimal = dato - (int(dato))

print(decimal)
```

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). ¿Cuál sería el resultado esperado? Si pongo 2.5 devuelve 0.5 y si pongo -2.5 devuelve -0.5. No es posible saber el resultado que quieres si no lo describes en la pregunta

Comment: O, ya que input devuelve una cadena...`dato = input("Dime un numero:"); print(numero.rsplit(".")[-1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma de hacerlo es tomando el valor absoluto del dato ingresado: la parte decimal de un número y su negativo son la misma:

```
dato = abs(float(input("dime un numero: ")))    
decimal = dato - (int(dato))    
print(decimal)
```